# Xcode 7 Launch Screen images dont load properly

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios9.1

I am trying to make some different launch screens with Xcode 7 ios9.1
for different iOS devices (iPhone iPad)

If you take a look at the following images this is what I've done

[image: sreen shot]

Here I have made exactly all the images dimensions that it needs and I have filled out all the table with the images. I have made this by right clicking and selecting New iOS Launch Image.

[image: Assets]

Here I have set the launch images from LaunchImage.
And here is the launch screen storyboard which I have left it empty.
[image: Storyboard]
Now, when I run the app, it doesn't load the loading screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Remove one String from your project info.Plist File for Launch splash screen.

It's `Launch screen interface file base name`.

I attach Screenshot for remove String in .plist file

Here you saw second line just remove from Your file

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did this and still i have the same problem.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios ..You need to change one more as i update my answer.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios  As per my screen please clear Launch screen File

Comment: Yeap its like this and still i have the same problem :(

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios Can you now update your screen shot of General tab & info.Plist tab for more information?

Comment: We dont have to because i cleaned the project and run it again and now its perfect! Life saviour :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96818/discussion-between-maulik-patel-and-kwnstantinos-natsios).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Maulik Patel`s answer, I found that if you set launch images improperly, maybe you need to delete the app on your iPhone or simulator, set launch images right and rebuild it again. It works for me. Maybe there is still some cache of settings in the app.