# Launch images not showing with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, asset-catalog, launchimage

I have set the launch images in an asset catalog (`LaunchImage`), which I've also set in the target's "General" tab in Xcode. The default `LaunchScreen` file was being shown when running the app, but I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424168/launch-images-show-black-when-using-asset-catalog) and I did what it is said there: to left empty the `Launch Screen File` parameter both in "General" tab and in .plist

But now, instead of showing the appropiate launch image from catalog or the default one, I'm showing a black screen...

I'm supporting only iPhone, and iOS 7, 8 & 9.

What could I be missing?

Thanks

**EDIT:** could this be because of incorrect image sizes? For example, for the iPhone Portrait Retina HD 5.5 I have a file of size 1242 x 2208 and name `launch_iPhone6Plus-Portrait@3x.png`, is that correct?

**EDIT 2:** This is what I have in the target's "General" tab.
[image: target settings]

Comment: Use image assets for Launch images in that case. Just drop two images of size 2x(640 x 960) and Retina 4(640 x 1136). Works fine for me.

Comment: @iAnum yes, that's what I'm trying, to take the launch images from the image assets... but it does not work

Comment: @AppsDev please check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043541/xcode-7-launch-screen-images-dont-load-properly/34043799#34043799

Answer (score 15):

Well what I've noticed that when you create a new project by default you will get `LaunchScreen.storyboard` as you **Launch Screen Image**.

But if you don't want to use `LaunchScreen.storyboard` then what you do is remove `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and **tap on Use Asset Catalog**.

But by default it will give you **Brand Asset** instead of **Launch Image** in Xcode Version 7.1.1.

Now click on the arrow besides **Brand Asses/Launch Image**. Xcode will navigate you to `Assets.xcasets` folder.

Now click on **+** below to add **App Icons & Launch Images**.

From there you need to select **New iOS Launch Image**. 
[image]

This is how your **LaunchImage** should be visible.
[image]

Now add the images according to size specified in the Apple Documentation. You can also get Launch Image Size from this url: [LaunchImageSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26191308/4101371)

Now go **application>Targets>General** and in **Launch Images Source** select **LaunchImage**.
[image]

Here is the image with **LaunchImage** added in `Assets.xcassets`.
[image]

Simulator Image on launching App.
[image]

Hope it helps in solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168145/whats-wrong-with-my-launch-images Any idea why? Thanks very much.

Comment: I just figured this out. My launch image was not showing up, I get a white screen when launching on a device (iPhone 6, 7+) or testFlight. Fix: Renamed "Landing_screen.png" to just "Landing_screen" removing .png part. The image icon in Xcode changed to white icon and in the launch screen storyboard the image appears as a question mark now. The Launch image now appears and not the white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the setting for your project so that it points to the Asset Catalog as the source for your Launch Image?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've just edited my question with a screenshot of what I have there.

Comment: add perfect size image for all device.

Comment: using inspector you can know what image size required.

Comment: I think I'm already doing that... is the example I provide in my question ok?